Why does calculus of variations problem turn into simple optimization problem when both start and end time variables are chosen to be free?
Consider a typical problem of calculus of variations:
$$\int^{t_1}_{t_0} F(x(t),\space x(t)’,\space t)dt \space \space x(t_1)=x_1 \space \space x(t_0)=x_0$$
Now assume that both $t_1$ and $t_2$ are free. In Kamien & Schwartz’s (2000) Part I Section 9 Exercise 3 they want you to prove that:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}F_x(x^{*}(t), \space x^{*}{’}(t), \space t)dt=0$$
, using DuBois-Reymond equation:
$$F_{x’}(x^{*}(t), \space x^{*}{’}(t), \space t)= \int_{t_0}^{t}F_x(x^{*}(s), \space x^{*}{’}(s), \space s)ds $$
Also, when both $t_1$ and $t_2$ are free, we have:
$$F(t_i,x(t_i),x’(t_i))-x’(t_i) F_{x’}(t_i,x(t_i),x’(t_i))=0, \space \space \space t \space \epsilon \left( 0,1 \right) $$
Given all the above information, how can we derive the proof?

Well, it is intuitively obvious that in free horizons case of calculus of variations problem (that is, both $t_1, \space t_0$ are free) the objective function under the integral sign does not depend on time variable at all, and the only thing you are left with is a function that depends on x, and therefore, $F_x=0$ if x is an optimal solution to finding the extremum of the function F.
For a more rigorous proof, first differentiate DuBois-Reymond Formula with respect to t, and you will get the standard Euler formula:
$$\frac{dF_{x’}}{dt}=F_x$$
Now since $F_x=0$ from the exercise, we only need to prove that $\frac{dF_{x’}}{dt}=0$. To do so, let’s make some use of the transversatility condition $F-x’F_{x’}=0$, from which $F_{x’}=\frac{F}{x’}$, and take the derivative of $\frac{dF_{x’}}{dt}$ using quotient rule:
$$\frac{dF_{x’}}{dt}=\frac{d\frac{F}{x’}}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dF}{dt}x’-x’’F}{(x’)^{2}}$$
Here we employ another useful alternative formulation of the Euler equation where $\frac{dF}{dt} =\frac{d(F-x’F_{x’})}{dt}$, hence, $x’F_{x’}=0$ and from transversatility condition that $F=x’F_{x’}=0$ we get:
$$\frac{dF_{x’}}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dF}{dt}x’-x’’F}{(x’)^{2}} =0$$
We have proved that for free endpoints, the calculus of variations problem turns into a typical calculus optimization problem.
